# How to calculate remaining balance by joining different tables in PowerPivot

Tags: excel, powerpivot, calculated-columns

I have the following structure in Powerpivot in Excel 2016.

[image]

EmployeeTable contains employee data. LeaveAvailableTable contains number of leaves that an employee can take. LeaveTable contains leave that employee has taken. Configuration contains leave title and code for e.g. 01, Annual; 02, Casual

I want to display a report like this:

`EmployeeName, LeaveTypeTitle, LeavesAvailable, LeavesTaken, RemainingBalance`

I am able to do a report where I can display everything except RemainingBalance. 
It will be calculated as follows:

`Remaining Balance = LeavesAvailable - LeavesTaken`

How do I show remaining balance by using DAX query or is there some other way?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

My report with RemainingBalance looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Why don't you use a nomrmal cell formula such as C5-D5?

Comment: I have done that but it doesn't look neat. Because let's say if 10 records are being displayed, and then I change filter above to show only 1 record then it will continue to show those 9 rows containing 0 instead of hiding those rows.

Comment: Here's how it will look like (just an example)

https://i.imgur.com/E8TnDs6.jpg  https://i.imgur.com/uk7zxn3.jpg